# Написание собственного класса/метода для вычисления корня n-ной степени (Java)

Tags: java, алгоритм, root

```
public class RootWhile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double z = 1, result = 0, x = 1, y = 0;
        double number = 123456789;
        double root = 125887;
        if(number < 0 & root % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Неверный ввод");
        }
        else if (root>0) {
            result = ((root-1)*1+number/1)/root;
            for(int i=1; i<root; i++){
                z*=result;}
            while (x-y>0){
                z=1;
                for(int j=1; j<root; j++){
                    z*=result;
                }
                result=((root-1)*result+number/z)/root;
                x=result;
                z=1;
                for(int j=1; j<root; j++){
                    z*=result;
                }
                result=((root-1)*result+number/z)/root;
                y=result;
            }
        }
        else if (root<0) {
            root=(-1)*root;
            result = ((root-1)*1+number/1)/root;
            for(int i=1; i<root; i++){
                z*=result;}
            while (x-y>0){
                z=1;
                for(int j=1; j<root; j++){
                    z*=result;
                }
                result=((root-1)*result+number/z)/root;
                x=result;
                z=1;
                for(int j=1; j<root; j++){
                    z*=result;
                }
                result=((root-1)*result+number/z)/root;
                y=result;
            }
            result=1/result;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Если с меленькими числами и степенями все хорошо, то с большими, как например в прикрепленном классе, все очень туго. Тогда как даже телефонный калькулятор дает ответ мгновенно. Что я делаю не так? Может я все неправильно делаю?)
Алгоритм нахождения корня [взят из Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F_n-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Comment: `if(number < 0 & root % 2 == 0){` - вы, кажется, забыли амперсанд

Comment: Вроде все на месте. Но дело не в этой части кода. больше вопросов возникает тут ==>>

    {
        result = ((root-1)*1+number/1)/root;
        for(int i=1; i<root; i++){ ...

Comment: Только зачем извращаться если есть Math.pow(number, 1.0 / N ), если есть потребность  скорости, то используйте Math.exp(Math.log(number)/N)

Comment: тут же весь интерес был сделать самому

Answer (score 1):

Практически некропост конечно, тем не менее:

```
    double number=2;
    int root=2;
    double x, pw, xprev=1;
    x=number;
    while(Math.abs(xprev-x) > 1.0e-10) {
        xprev=x;
        pw=1;
        for(int i=0; i < (root-1); i++)
           pw*=xprev;
        x=1.0/root*((root-1)*xprev+number/pw);
        //System.out.println("x="+x+", xprev="+xprev+", pw="+pw);
    }

    System.out.println("number root="+x);
```

Ошибка ТС в том, что надо:

1. Задаваться дельтой (точностью вычислений)
2. Степень должна быть целая
3. Итерация в цикле должна быть 1 (а не две как у него)

Answer (score -1):

x^(1/n) = exp(ln(x)/n).
А если хочется поупражняться - можно порешать эту проблему для длинной целочисленной арифметики (существуют алгоритмы извлечения корня наибольшей возможной степени со скоростью, линейно зависящей от разрядности числа).